# Disable copy-past premission in iOS 16.1

Tags: swift, uipasteboard

as you may know, iOS 16 introduced a bug that when your app use `UIPasteboard`it keeps asking for permission every time. This annoying alert is gone after 16.1 as I heard, but still see it. User must go to the app setting in the iOS setting and change `Paste from other apps` to `allow`.

Is there anyway to do it on app that user doesn't need to do those crazy steps? Otherwise we should inform every user to do that to get rid of that alert.

Would be so grateful if you can give me a good hint to fix it. Maybe some privacy key on `info.plist`?

here is my simple code to read from clipboard

```
  private func getURLFromClipboard() {
    
    let pasteboardString: String? = UIPasteboard.general.string
    if let string = pasteboardString {

        if validateUrl(urlString: string as NSString) {
            presentShareURL(url: string)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No one has any idea?

Comment: No one knows any way?

Comment: I think you need to use the new UIPasteControl class, docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipastecontrol)